# Most home runs in first n games of the season

Tags: baseball, mlb, records

Adrian Gonzalez of the Los Angeles Dodgers has now hit 5 home runs in the first 3 games of the 2015 season.

Is this a major league record for most home runs in the first 3 games of a season?

In general, is there somewhere I can find records for most home runs in the first *n* games of a season, for various values of *n*?

Answer (score 4):

To answer the first question, according to Fox Sports this is a record (since 1970).

**Update:** Listening to Mike and Mike (ESPN Radio) this morning they quoted Elias Sports Bureau in saying that this is the most home runs through three games in the *history* of baseball.

The previous record through three games was a tie between three players with four home runs:

- Vernon Wells, 2010 with Toronto
- Chris Shelton, 2006 with Detroit
- Barry Bonds, 2002 with San Francisco

[Fox Sports Link](https://twitter.com/foxsportslive/status/586043023286349824)

As for the second part, I have not seen a publicly searchable database with that fine of granularity.

Comment: Is there any reason for the 1970 cutoff, or is that just the time period that Fox Sports were able to check?

Answer (score 3):

According to this [ESPN article](http://espn.go.com/los-angeles/mlb/story/_/id/12651692/adrian-gonzalez-los-angeles-dodgers-records-first-3-homer-game), the Elias Sports Bureau says Adrian Gonzalez set a new record by hitting 5 HRs in the first three games of the season:

> Adrian Gonzalez set a major league record by clubbing five home runs in the Los Angeles Dodgers' first three games, according to the Elias Sports Bureau.

As for finding the most home runs in the first *n* games of a season, I don't think there is anything.  I checked baseball-reference.com's [Batting Game Finder](http://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/game_finder.cgi?type=b), and it doesn't appear to have that capability.